# Deleting objects in a specific folder using sweep policy

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

I have several folders inside my object store, and i want to implement a sweep policy for housekeeping. The idea is that any files/subfolders/documents inside one of my several "main" folders needs to be deleted if they are more than one month old.

I understand that i can do this by using sweep policy, but i have no idea about how to do it.

Probably something to mention, all subfolders in my object store have their own class, but the main folders share one class, "Folder".
Can anyone help with a guide or something about this? I've been to the IBM site and it's not helping much.
Thanks.

Comment: What is exactly your problem? Have you read [Disposal Policies Concepts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/disposalpolicy_concepts.htm) and [Working with Disposal Policies](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/disposalpolicy_procedures.htm)?

Comment: yeah, i've read those. that sample deletes objects based on its class, but in my case, i want to delete everything under a specific folder, and under that folder only. if i implement a sweep based on class, objects in another folders may get deleted.

Comment: You mean it's not possible to use [`INFOLDER` operator](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/query_sql_syntax_rel_queries.htm#query_sql_syntax_rel_queries__folder_operators) in the policy's filter expression?

Comment: huh, that might help. i haven;t tried that one yet.

Comment: @fnt it didnt work. it returned an SQL error saying that the INFOLDER operator is not a valid operator.

Comment: Finally i used CONTAINS operator. it should be working, but my object store is not configured or CBR yet. On other note, does disposal of a folder automatically deletes the contents of that folder as well?

Comment: Well, this probably means `INFOLDER` is not supported in filter expressions. I don't have running system at hand to confirm this. `CONTAINS` has nothing to do with folders. It searches for text in documents. I suggest that you carefully read the documentation though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, with @fnt 's help:

Object deletion automated by using disposal policy, not the standard sweep. Disposal policy deletes things in the object store based on the *object class*.
Since the target of my disposal already has a class, i can just use that as the base.

The Filter expression is an SQL WHERE query, this is what i put in it:

```
DateCreated < Now() - Timespan (30, 'Days') AND PathName LIKE '%Application%'
```

Both INFOLDER and CONTAINS did not work. While i still cannot figure out why INFOLDER doesn't work, CONTAINS apparently requires both the object store and object class of your disposal to be CBR-enabled, which i don't have.